# Wrap generator into a buffer?

Tags: python, buffer, generator, wsgi, bytesio

I have a python generator that yields parts of a file (a wsgi `app_iter`) and I need to pass it to an interface that expects it to have the classical `read` and `readlines` methods (I want to pass it as `wsgi.input` of another `Request`).

Is is possible to do it in a way that does not materialize the whole generator content into memory? The idea is to wrap the generator in something that has `read` and `readline` (such as `BytesIO` or `StringIO`) and do it in a lazy fashion.

Comment: "If the file is line-based, the file object is already a lazy generator of lines" https://stackoverflow.com/a/519653/952234.

Answer (score 3):

It's certainly possible. Here's a woefully-inefficient piece of code to give you the idea:

```
class ReadWrapper:
    def __init__(self, app_iter):
        self.iterator = iter(app_iter)
        self.buffer = ''
    def readline(self):
        while '\n' not in self.buffer:
            try:
                self.buffer += next(self.iterator)
            except StopIteration:
                result = self.buffer
                self.buffer = ''
                return result
        idx = self.buffer.find('\n')
        result = self.buffer[:idx+1]
        self.buffer = self.buffer[idx+1:]
        return result
```

`read()` would be similar except that instead of looking for `\n`, you're looking for the specified number of bytes (or the end of the iterator if no size is specified).

The woeful inefficiency of the above code is in the way it handles `self.buffer`: you don't really want to be searching the whole thing for `\n` at every step, or doing so many potentially large copies.

Comment: I thought that there was something already in the standard library or at least in PYPI, it seems to be something good to put in a library